# How to get reference to EXPECT_CALL argument

Tags: c++, pointers, googlemock

I want to get references to the MyObjectClass instance passed to "somePrivateMethod" called by myMock.

Now I use the following snippet but I'm sure there is a better way.

```
namespace {
MyObjectClass *myObjectPtr;

ACTION( getIt )
{
   myObjectPtr = &arg0;
}
}
...

...

EXPECT_CALL( *myMock, somePrivateMethod( testing::_ ) ).WillOnce( testing::WithArg< 0 >( getIt( ) ) );
```

My problem is clearly stated I need to get the reference to that argument. The reason for what I want it has no matter here. I only need to know how to set a pointer to the argument of the somePrivateMethod.

Comment: your code should test class behavior not its internal implementation. Also question is so badly stated that it is hard to comprehend it. So I'm suspecting [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I don't want to test it. I need to get access to the private member in this case b, but it can be any object. Mock use that object as an argument. I try to use SaveArg, SaveArgPointee but they just copy value.

Comment: if you don't want to test it, so why you are using `gtest` and `gmock`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do this is write public `get` method in declaration of `class A`

`public:
   const int * get_b { return &b; }`

But since you want to check the value of this variable you don't need a pointer and can return value of variable in `get` function

`public:
   int get_b { return b; }`

Comment: I can't change the code I need to get access to the private object which is used as an argument of function which is mocked.

Comment: Since you can't change the code then you can't get access to private member of `class A`.  Only class methods and `friend` functions can access to private members.